How to add intervals to the x axis (factor levels) and stat bars in R ggplot
I create this plot in R: 
I want to do 2 things:

Add more factor levels to the x axis (intervals of 12hrs to match other data), I try with scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 72, by = 12), labels = seq(0, 72, by = 12)) and other combinations but always return error.
add statistical values with bars instead of stars.

the code I try is here:
plot01 <- ggplot(df02_EC_01, aes(x=hrs, y=Vol_mm3, fill=Temp, color=Temp)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", 
               stackdir = "centerwhole", 
               alpha = .5, 
               dotsize = .3, 
               method = "histodot", 
               binwidth = 1, 
               stackratio = 1, 
               position = "dodge",
               binpositions="all") +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T,  size= .5, coef=500, alpha=.5) +
  labs(title = "Decalcification Process with EDTA",
       # subtitle = "EDTA",
       # caption = "Data from p02-g01&02.R",
       #tag = "Figure 1",
       x = "Hours",
       y = "Mineralized tissue (mm3)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group=Temp), label = "p.signif") + 
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 72, by = 12), labels = seq(0, 72, by = 12)) + # ERROR!!
  ylim(0,30) 

I include a dput of a sample of the data:
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Temp = c("RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
"RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
"RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
"RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
"RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
"37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", 
"37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", 
"37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", 
"37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C", "37C"), Cond. = c("EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
"EC", "EC", "EC", "EC"), hrs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("0", 
"12", "24", "48", "72", "96", "120", "144"), class = "factor"), 
    Side = c("L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
    "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R"
    ), Vol_mm3 = c(26.64, 26.29, 20.33, 20.67, 15.17, 14.7, 5.62, 
    5.33, 3.72, 3.73, 3.93, 3.71, 4.34, 3.61, 2.22, 2.18, 21.27, 
    21.72, 14.92, 15, 7.17, 7.6, 3.29, 3.78, 2.36, 2.35, 2.95, 
    2.9, 0.88, 0.85, 0.72, 0.78, 25.25, 25.26, 17.56, 18.1, 10.19, 
    10.4, 5.89, 5.9, 4.92, 4.49, 1.03, 1, 2.26, 2.17, 1.83, 1.67, 
    24.4, 23.71, 6.59, 6.24, 4.24, 3.82, 2.28, 2.05, 1.03, 0.98, 
    22.93, 25.05, 6.75, 6.74, 4.21, 4.49, 2.33, 2.59, 1.06, 1.23, 
    0.07, 0.17, 24.04, 22.86, 7.1, 6.1, 4.01, 4.74, 2.99, 2.33, 
    1.24, 1.11, 0.13, 0.13)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -82L), groups = structure(list(
    hrs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("0", "12", "24", "48", "72", 
    "96", "120", "144"), class = "factor"), Cond. = c("EC", "EC", 
    "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", "EC", 
    "EC", "EC"), Temp = c("37C", "RT", "37C", "RT", "37C", "RT", 
    "37C", "RT", "37C", "RT", "37C", "RT", "RT", "RT"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(49L, 50L, 59L, 60L, 71L, 72L), c(1L, 2L, 17L, 18L, 
        33L, 34L), c(51L, 52L, 61L, 62L, 73L, 74L), c(3L, 4L, 
        19L, 20L, 35L, 36L), c(53L, 54L, 63L, 64L, 75L, 76L), 
        c(5L, 6L, 21L, 22L, 37L, 38L), c(55L, 56L, 65L, 66L, 
        77L, 78L), c(7L, 8L, 23L, 24L, 39L, 40L), c(57L, 58L, 
        67L, 68L, 79L, 80L), c(9L, 10L, 25L, 26L, 41L, 42L), 
        c(69L, 70L, 81L, 82L), c(11L, 12L, 27L, 28L, 43L, 44L
        ), c(13L, 14L, 29L, 30L, 45L, 46L), c(15L, 16L, 31L, 
        32L, 47L, 48L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .drop = TRUE))

Thank you for your support.

Your example data has hours as a factor, which already doesn't include 36, 60 hours etc. Possibly the issue is in the step prior to this where you ended up with limited number of hour factors in the first place? And stat_compare_means is not in ggplot2, please provide library information in your example.

I suggest using the ggpubr / rstatix packages.
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

We need to do the tests, and then fill in the missing levels so that the plot works.
stat.test <- df02_EC_01 %>%
  group_by(hrs) %>%
  filter(!hrs %in% c("120","144")) %>%  # omit these rows
  t_test(Vol_mm3 ~ Temp) %>%
  mutate(p=ifelse(p<0.001, "p<0.001", round(p, 3))) %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "hrs") %>%
  add_row(hrs='36', .after=3) %>%
  add_row(hrs='60', .after=5) %>%
  add_row(hrs='84', .after=7) %>%
  mutate(xmin=seq(first(xmin), length.out=n()),
         xmax=seq(first(xmax), length.out=n()))


df02_EC_01 %>%
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(ID=1,
               Temp=df02_EC_01$Temp[1],
               Cond.=df02_EC_01$Cond.[1],
               hrs=setdiff(as.character(seq(0,144,12)), 
                           levels(df02_EC_01$hrs)),
               Side=df02_EC_01$Side[1],
               Vol_mm3=NA)
  ) %>%
  mutate(hrs=factor(hrs, levels=c(seq(0,144,12)))) %>%
  ggboxplot(x = "hrs", y = "Vol_mm3", fill = "Temp")  + 
  labs(y=expression(Mineralized~tissue~(mm^3)),
       x="Hours") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p", tip.length = 0.01, size=3)




If you add the missing levels to the hrs variable, you should get the desired plot.
df02_EC_01 %>%
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(ID=1,
               Temp=df02_EC_01$Temp[1],
               Cond.=df02_EC_01$Cond.[1],
               hrs=setdiff(as.character(seq(0,144,12)), 
                           levels(df02_EC_01$hrs)),
               Side=df02_EC_01$Side[1],
               Vol_mm3=NA)
  ) %>%
  mutate(hrs=factor(hrs, levels=c(seq(0,144,12)))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=hrs, y=Vol_mm3, fill=Temp, color=Temp)) +
...



